# Regularity of solution to first order time dependent variational problem

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

Consider the following first order evolution problem over some regular bounded domain $\Omega\subset\Bbb R^d$
$$\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial t}(\mathbf{x},t) +\vec V(\mathbf{x},t)\cdot \nabla\phi(\mathbf{x},t)=f(\mathbf{x},t),\;\;\;\;(\mathbf{x},t)\in \Omega\times [0,T),\;\;\;T\in\mathbb{R},\tag{1}\label{1}$$
where we are given $$\phi(\mathbf{x},0)=\phi_0\in H^1(\Omega),\;\; f\in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega)),\;\; \text{ and }\;\;\vec{V}\in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))^2.$$
If we fix $s\in [0,T)$, the variational form of the above equation at time $s$ reads as
$$ \int\limits_\Omega \frac{\partial \phi(s)}{\partial t}v+\int\limits_\Omega (\vec V(s)\cdot \nabla\phi(s))v = \int\limits_\Omega f(s)v,\;\;\;\forall v\in H^1(\Omega).$$
For any $t<T$, we can integrate the above equation from 0 to $t$ to get
$$\int\limits_\Omega(\phi(t)-\phi_0)v=-\int\limits_0^t\int\limits_\Omega (\vec V(s)\cdot \nabla\phi(s))v +\int\limits_0^t\int\limits_\Omega f(s)v,\;\;\;\forall v\in H^1(\Omega).\tag{2}\label{2}$$
Suppose that we are given $\phi\in L^2(0,T;H^1(\Omega))$ which satisfies \eqref{2} for almost all $t\in[0,T)$. The question is: under the above assumptions, can we hope to show that $\phi\in H^1(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$ also, and try to recover a classical solution of \eqref{1}? If not, what conditions on $f$, $\vec{V}$ and $\phi_0$ are needed to recover a classical solution?

Comment: +1. Nice question

Comment: @DanieleTampieri thanks! though I would've also enjoyed a nice answer! I think the way the question is asked is too general and some more assumptions are needed here and there

Comment: Perhaps the problem is not in the way the question is asked, but in the lack of specific expertise in MO: not all research mathematicians not experts participate to the community so it is difficult to find an answer to several (even very) interesting questions. However, just to follow an intuition, you may have a look to the book by Jan Prüss, *Evolutionary integral equations and applications*, Birkhäuser (1993), [MR1238939](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR1238939), [Zbl 0784.45006](https://www.zbmath.org/?q=an%3A0784.45006): perhaps you'll find something useful there.